# Sending a byte[] buffer via serial

Tags: java, android, outputstream

I have a working code where I send the following array of byte[] via `FileOutputStream outputstream.write` method

```
private void SendPacket(int numBytes)
    {   
        try {
            if(outputstream != null){

                outputstream.write(writeusbdata,0,8);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And I'm receiving

```
14:50:02.374 [<--------] RECV: 30 31 20 30 36 20 34 45
```

which is nice, but when I replace `writeusbdata` with

```
byte[] writeusbdata = {(byte) 01, (byte) 06, (byte) 78, (byte) 140, (byte) 00, (byte) 01, (byte) 158, (byte) 201};
outputstream.write(writeusbdata,0,8);
```

I receive

```
15:05:50.414 [<--------] RECV: 06 78 F8 98 E0 E0 00 06 F8 78 18
```

### - Why am I receiving more bytes than it should? Why are they different from the buffer?

### - What is the appropriate way to send this byte[] buffer?

> Please note: This is an Android Accessory application

Comment: How are you receiving and logging the data?

Comment: I'm using Modlink VCL Demo monitor
http://www.ozm.cz/ivobauer/modlink/

Comment: maybe it's a problem with OutputStream.write ?

Comment: That seems unlikely, but you should put more context into your question, including exactly where you're logging.

Comment: What type of OutputStream is it? (Is it a WriterOutputStream by any chance?)

Comment: It's a FileOutputStream

Comment: So you are writing to a file. Use a HexViewer/Editor to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Solved by my own.

This is the correct approach to generate the `byte[] buffer` before sending it

```
byte[] b = {(byte) 01, (byte) 06, (byte) 78, (byte) 140, (byte) 00, (byte) 01, (byte) 158, (byte) 201};

        /*prepare the packet to be sent*/
        for(int count = 0;count<b.length;count++)
        {   
            writeusbdata[count] = b[count];
        }
```

Comment: Weird. You are just copying from a `byte[]` to another `byte[]` without any transformation. There was certainly something else...